# Objective-C/ALAssetslibrary - Take gps latitude from image exif informations

Tags: objective-c, exif, alassetslibrary

I have found from one image some exif informations about gps using the ALAssetslibrary. I can show correctly the entire exit informations, but when i try to take only the Latitude, i'm receiving always null.
This is the exif informations about GPS:

```
"{GPS}" =     {
    Altitude = 0;
    AltitudeRef = 1;
    DateStamp = "0111:06:09";
    Latitude = "45.84633333333333";
    LatitudeRef = N;
    Longitude = "12.58";
    LongitudeRef = E;
    TimeStamp = "10:39:04.00";
};
```

And this is the code that i'm using for take informations:

```
__block NSConditionLock * assetsReadLock = [[NSConditionLock alloc] initWithCondition:WDASSETURL_PENDINGREADS];
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ 
__block ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
__block NSString *description = [[NSString alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if (group) {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
            if (asset){
                NSDictionary *data = [[asset defaultRepresentation] metadata];
                NSLog(@"DATA: %@", data);

                NSNumber *width = [[[asset defaultRepresentation] metadata] objectForKey:@"PixelWidth"];
                NSString *widthString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", width];
                [widthList addObject:widthString];

                NSNumber *height = [[[asset defaultRepresentation] metadata] objectForKey:@"PixelHeight"];
                NSString *heightString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", height];
                [heightList addObject:heightString];

                NSString *latitude = [[[asset defaultRepresentation] metadata] objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
                NSLog(@"latitude %@", latitude);
                NSString *latitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", latitude];
                if(latitude != NULL){
                    [latitudeList addObject:latitude];
                } else {
                    NSString *noLatitude = [[NSString alloc] init];
                    noLatitude = @"No latitude available";
                    [latitudeList addObject:noLatitude];
                }
            }
        }];
    }
```

Well, at this point i can take easily the informations about width and height of the image, but when i try to take Latitude or Longitude i'm always receiving null. What i'm doing wrong?

Thank for help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a catch.  The default representation returned from the assets library has stripped things like EXIF data from the image so that's why you can't find it.

What I found was that if I extract the bytes that form the image manually, I could reconstruct the image and then get the EXIF data from it.

Here's a function that will get the bytes and return them as an NSData object:

```
@implementation PhotoLibrary

...

#define MAX_IMAGE_SIZE_LIKELY (700 * 1024)

static uint8_t assetBytes[MAX_IMAGE_SIZE_LIKELY];

+ (NSData*) getDataFromAsset:(ALAsset*)asset {
ALAssetRepresentation* rep = [asset representationForUTI:(NSString*)kUTTypeJPEG];

    if (rep != nil) {
      [rep getBytes:assetBytes fromOffset:0 length:[rep size] error:NULL];
      return [NSData dataWithBytes:assetBytes length:[rep size]];
    } else {
      // Return nil, indicating that the image was no good.
      //
      return nil;
    }
}

...

@end
```

Note that in my case I was limiting the size of the image to 700K (I had other check-code in there that wasn't relevant to your question).

Now, some code (in the same utility class) that calls this is a function I have in uAlertMe that scans the asset library for images that match various criteria:

```
// Return an array of matching images.
//
+ (void) getImagesForDate:(NSDate *)forDate
         matchDateAndTime:(BOOL)matchDateAndTime
      andMatchUserComment:(NSString*)userComment
      withCompletionBlock:(PhotoLibraryRetrievalCompletetionBlock)completionBlock {
    NSMutableArray* result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if ([PhotoLibrary isAssetsLibraryAvailable]) {
        ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock assetEnumerator =
        ^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if(asset != NULL) {
                NSDictionary *dict = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs];

                if ([[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto] == YES) {

                    // We've been asked to match the date and time, so that means
                    // that we need to get the image data itself so that we can
                    // get the EXIF metadata from within it.
                    //
                    NSData* repData = [PhotoLibrary getDataFromAsset:asset];

                    if (repData != nil) {
                        NSString* comment = [EXIFUtility userCommentForPhoto:repData];

                        if ((userComment != nil) && [comment isEqualToString:userComment]) {
                            // OK so the user comment matches.  Does the date match?
                            NSDate* date = [EXIFUtility dateDigitizedForPhoto:repData];

                            if (matchDateAndTime) {
                                // We want an exact match.
                                if ([date isEqualToDate:forDate]) {
                                    [result addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:repData]];
                                }
                            } else {
                                // We simply want a match on date, regardless of the time of day.
                                if ([date isSameDay:forDate]) {
                                    [result addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:repData]];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock assetGroupEnumerator =
        ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
            @try {
                if(group != nil) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
                        completionBlock(result);
                        [result removeAllObjects];
                        [result release];
                    });
                }
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception) {
                DDLogError(@"Exception whilst enumerating group: %@", exception);
                *stop = true;
            }
        };

        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [PhotoLibrary defaultAssetsLibrary];

        [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                               usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                             failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                                 DDLogError(@"getImagesForDate:forDate matchDateAndTime:  failed with error: %@", error);
                                 completionBlock(nil);
                                 [result removeAllObjects];
                                 [result release];
                             }];
    } else {
        completionBlock(nil);
        [result removeAllObjects];
        [result release];
    }
}
```

A Mac OS X version of the EXIFUtility class can be found at:

[EXIFUtility.h](http://sourceforge.net/p/ialertu/code/ci/master/tree/EXIFUtility.h)
[EXIFUtility.m](http://sourceforge.net/p/ialertu/code/ci/master/tree/EXIFUtility.m)

These are very similar to what I have in uAlertMe and should provide you with enough information.